# UITableView Cell Reuse & Old Data

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I would like to confirm the approach I took to solve an issue with dequeuing custom cells in a `UITableView` as it scrolls such that the cells do not contain the old cell's data...

The app that contains a `UITableView` with custom `UITableViewCells` ("CustomCell").  Each CustomCell contains a `UIStackView` with one or more custom views via a nib ("CustomView").  I reuse the CustomCell as follows:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(ReuseIdentifierCustomCell, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CustomCell
    configureCell(cell, atIndexPath: indexPath)
    return cell
}
```

The issue was that the cell would contain "old" data as the cell was being reused.  To fix this, I override the `prepareForReuse` method in CustomCell as follows:

```
override func prepareForReuse() {
    super.prepareForReuse()

    for case let view as CustomView in stackView.subviews {
        view.removeFromSuperview()
    }
}
```

Then in `layoutSubviews`, I add the subviews back in:

```
override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()

    if stackView.subviews.isEmpty {
        addCustomViewsToCell()
    }
}
```

Performance seems fine thus far, but curious if this is a proper approach or if I will run into issues with scale in the future.  I have not been able to find another workable approach thus far.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your code to reuse cells is correct. A common approach is to configure your cell's data within the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` function by setting a variable or calling a function on your custom cell:

```
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(ReuseIdentifierCustomCell, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CustomCell
cell.data = myData[indexPath.row] // where myData is an array of type [Data]
return cell
```

Your cell would be in charge of its own layout to display the new data:

```
var data: Data {
    didSet {
        // configure and refresh your UI here
    }
}
```

I suspect your issue has to do with your `configureCell` function. If you can, move this code into your cell's logic instead. This will be cleaner and easier to understand.

As far as performance, you might be fine now if your stack views don't have much content in them, but if they continue to grow in complexity you might see frame rate drops on older devices.

Comment: Putting `configureCell` in the cell subclass violates MVC. It will work, but it isn't best practice.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions.  The `configureCell` function really was just setting the data value, which I moved to the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` for clarity.  That said, the reuse problem still appeared without removing the `CustomView` from the hierarchy when the cell is being prepared for reuse.  Perhaps because I am adding the subviews instead of updating?  The number of subviews can change between cells, which makes it a bit trickier as well.